# SELECT inner Join Group by sub query extract in a single row

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my Query

```
SELECT * FROM pendingtreatment 
   INNER JOIN tbl_finds_d 
   ON tbl_appointments 
   ON pendingtreatment.pid = tbl_finds_d.pid
```

**Pendingtreatment** table

```
id  treatment    pid
 1  Rehabilation  5
 2  Extraction    5
```

**tbl_appointments** table

```
id  appointment  pid
 1  18-03-2020    5
```

**tbl_finds_d** table

```
id  finds      pid
 1  Allergy     5
 2  Sugar       5
 3  BP          5
```

Comment: And your question is ... ?

Comment: what is your expected result

Comment: mysql or sqlite?

Comment: Extract data in single row like Pendingtreatment (rehabilation, Extraction) appointment (18-03-2020) finds (allergy, sugar, bp) pid(5)

Comment: @hoangnh Any idea?

Comment: You need to review join syntax and research group_concat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presuming that you want to join three tables to get the desired data on foreign key pid

then sql should look like below :

```
SELECT pdt.treatment, aps.appointments, fd.finds
FROM pendingtreatment as pdt
INNER JOIN tbl_finds_d as fd
   ON pendingtreatment.pid = tbl_finds_d.pid
JOIN tbl_appointments as aps
   ON pendingtreatment.pid = tbl_appointments.pid
```